# Can't test gst-rtsp-server

Tags: vlc, gstreamer, rtsp

Related to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095521/cant-build-gst-rtsp-server) (read first for context)

I managed to manually compile the `gst-rtsp-server`.

I then tried to use the test-launch example given within the github repo I cloned.

```
$ cd (myRepo)/gst-rtsp-server/examples
$ ./test-launch "( videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

I then downloaded VLC media player and launched it within a terminal,
but when I try to play the resulting stream `rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test`, I get errors. 
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Why can't VLC connect to my rstp server and stream what's diffused(the test video)?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. My workaround right now is to launch Firefox and enter rtsp://(ip):(port)/test. This allows me to launch either VLC or the built-in Videos application in Ubuntu. Both work fine when launched from Firefox.

Comment: If I remember correctly, my problem was that the virtual machine I was using was using a `NAT` `Network Adapter` instead of the recommended `Bridged` one. Hope this info helps!