# Can't install wireshark on ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, ppa, wireshark

I created a brand new Ubuntu vm with beaver GUI but can't install wireshark on it.

I used the steps provided on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700712/how-to-install-wireshark) to get wireshark from ppa, but I get errors of dependencies or something...

STEPS:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

ERRORS:
[image]

**EDIT 1:**
I tried to install `wireshark-qt` but I get the same type of error...
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I tried solutions from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages), but none seem to help my case.

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I tried the many solutions provided by your link, but without success... `$ sudo apt-get autoremove` and `$ sudo apt-get update` didn't change a thing.. ): Thanks for your help! I'll keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to install from the Wireshark development PPA. It probably needs resources that are not available on 18.04.1.

---

**Update #1:**

There could also be a problem with "Beaver GUI"... I'm not familiar with it. Sounds like GNOME desktop.

This originally started as a server install, and other resources may be missing that are required for Wireshark.

---

Remove or disable the PPA.

Then checkmark the following Ubuntu repositories... and reload the databases on quit...

[image]

Then install Wireshark from Synaptic, the Software Center, or...

In `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get update` # update the software databases

`sudo apt-get install wireshark` # install wireshark

Comment: So the problem is coming from the PPA repo. Thanks for the quick help! (:

Comment: @LoukMo also check your "Beaver GUI".

Comment: The "Beaver GUI" I'm referencing to is (I think) the basic one you get from doing [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)'s commands... `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` I thought it was called beaver because there's a beaver as default wallpaper... hahah

Comment: @LoukMo That's probably GNOME desktop. Was/is your installation originally a server install?

Comment: I used the `ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso` as base for my vm. You can see the steps I used to make the vm at the start of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095521/cant-build-gst-rtsp-server).

Comment: @LoukMo ah... that's why you needed to install ubuntu-desktop. There may be other resources missing in server that are required for Wireshark. Is Wireshark working for you now?

Comment: Hi @heynnema, can you help with [this proxy question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161956/439867) where  Wireshark was suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bsh
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then install with:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```